# Perl, pattern matching and metacharacters

Tags: perl, metacharacters

I am trying to match two things which both are full of metacharacters that needs to be used as 'Literal' in my match pattern.  `\Q` is suppose to quote all metacharacter in a string until `\E`...but it doesn't work.

Whats up with that?

this is the line that gives me trouble :  `if (/\Q$prev\E/ !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/) {`

Comment: You can't compare two regular expressions like that. Could you post more of your code and clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Do you want `$prev` and `$ww[0]` to be interpolated or don't you?

Comment: What makes you think that the metaquoting isn't happening? You might want to see [Understand the order of operations in double quoted contexts](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1496) for some ways you can explore that.

Answer (score 11):

Absent the use of `=~` or `!~`,

```
/.../
```

is short for

```
$_ =~ m/.../
```

so

```
/\Q$prev\E/ !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/
```

is short for

```
($_ =~ /\Q$prev\E/) !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/
```

which is equivalent to one of the following depending on whether the left regex match succeeds or not:

```
"" !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/
"1" !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/
```

You simply want:

```
$prev !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/   # $ww[0] doesn't contains $prev
```

If you actually want

```
$prev !~ /^\Q$ww[0]\E\z/   # $ww[0] isn't equal to $prev
```

then you can simplify that to

```
$prev ne $ww[0]   # $ww[0] isn't equal to $prev
```

By the way, always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It may have identified a problem here (but not necessarily, depending on the value of `$_`).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to compare a string in `$prev` to one in `$ww[0]`. If this is the case, a regex match should look like this:

```
$result = $prev !~ /\Q$ww[0]\E/
```

`$result` will return `1` if `$prev` is not the same as whatever is in `www[0]`, ignoring metacharacters.

However if that is all you wanted to do, you might as well use `ne`:

```
if ($prev ne $ww[0]){ 
   #do this if $prev and $ww[0] are not the same
}
```

---

Also, as @toolic has mentioned, add the following line to the top of your script:

```
use warnings;
```

This will give you some feedback on possible problems in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your help!!  I was over complicating things as usual :).  ($prev ne $ww[0]) worked just fine.